# JUCE ViewPort how to

Tags: c++, juce

I have a component called Obstacle and I am using it as a component from my mainContentComponent using addAndMakeVisible and setBounds function. I wish to scroll this Obstacle component across my window, with respect to time. I am using a timer and setBounds function to do this.

I realize that using setBounds calls the paint function everytime, and that my component is created everytime the paint function is called. I would like to use the viewPort class and pass my component to a viewport object using the setViewedComponent class. I used the API, but not much has helped. Can someone point me to examples as to how to use the ViewPort, to scroll my juce::component across the window?

Many thanks.

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so, please mark it as accepted or state why the  answer is not sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in thinking that you should use `Viewport::setViewedComponent` for this purpose.

For example:

```
myViewport.setViewedComponent (new MyComponent());
```

The viewport will handle the lifetime of the component for you.

You don't state exactly what problem you're having, but a common mistake is to forget to set the size of the viewed component. You can do this with `Component::setSize` inside your class to be viewed.

For example:

```
MyComponent::MyComponent()
{
    setSize (100, 100);
}
```

---

More information on `Viewport` can be found [here](https://docs.juce.com/master/classViewport.html). 
More information on `Component` can be found [here](https://docs.juce.com/master/classComponent.html).